# iOS app hanging when swiping notification centre up and down

Tags: ios, freeze, notificationcenter

My app will freeze/hang on occasion after swiping to show the notification centre, and swiping to remove it. Its my understanding that this should not have any impact on my app as it does not place the app in the background or raise any events.

Does anybody have any idea why this would affect my app?

Comment: Do you have any gesture recognizers in that ViewController?

Comment: It´s unlikely that anyone can give you answers without giving detailed information and relevant code. I.e. if you have gesture recognizer show the code that responds to gestures.

Comment: I'll have to check. If this is the case do you think that it could possibly be losing the first responder when the notification centre is covering the app? If so this gives me a new avenue of investigation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to iOS 9, and the issue has not occurred since. So I am assuming this was a bug in iOS 8.1.4